# Firebase Dynamic Link Custom Domain Setup URL patterns to whitelist Error

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links, custom-domain

My custom domain https://mysub.mydomain.com is registered to Firebase Hosting correctly and I can create dynamic link with using my custom domain.But 3 warning occurs and IOS dynamic link is not open my IOS App.

If I use google default domain "xxx.page.link" , everything is ok.

The dynamic link has 3 warning(s)

We could not find Android package name 'xxxxx' in your Google project. Learn more.

We could not find bundle ID 'xxxxxxx' in your Google project. Learn more.

There is no configuration to prevent phishing on this domain https://mysub.mydomain.com/example. Setup URL patterns to whitelist in the Firebase Dynamic Links console. Learn more.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue? Specifically the "We could not find bundle ID 'xxxxxxx' in your Google project." warning?

Answer (score 4):

Issues about package and bundle should be fixed in firebase console project settings. You need to check that your iOS and android apps listed here have package name and bundle Id.

Last issue warns you about whitelisting your domains so that nobody could create dynamic links for you app passing links to random domains.

To handle it you need to tap on three dots near the add dynamic link button in firebase console and add all you domains (regex accepted) that can be used in your dynamic links.

Comment: Why clicking on URL prefix also opens app? As i have mentioned 10 whitelist url pattern. Still any path prefix with my URL scheme opens my app. Please suggest.